# jmp instruction difference in assembly code when used goto between with C and C++

Tags: c++, c, assembly, visual-studio-2022

I am using same code snippet in C and C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    goto myLabel;
    printf("skipped\n");
myLabel:
    printf("after myLabel\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2022 IDE and Compiler.

Assembly Code for C++

```
0000000140001000  sub         rsp,28h  
0000000140001004  jmp         0000000140001014  
0000000140001006  jmp         0000000140001014  
0000000140001008  lea         rcx,[0000000140004230h]  
000000014000100F  call        0000000140001090  
0000000140001014  lea         rcx,[0000000140004240h]  
000000014000101B  call        0000000140001090  
0000000140001020  xor         eax,eax  
0000000140001022  add         rsp,28h  
0000000140001026  ret
```

Assembly Code for C

```
0000000140001000  sub         rsp,28h  
0000000140001004  jmp         0000000140001012  
0000000140001006  lea         rcx,[0000000140006000h]  
000000014000100D  call        0000000140001090  
0000000140001012  lea         rcx,[0000000140006010h]  
0000000140001019  call        0000000140001090  
000000014000101E  xor         eax,eax  
0000000140001020  add         rsp,28h  
0000000140001024  ret
```

Question is why C++ assembly code uses 2 **jmp** instructions when C is using 1.

Comment: You are comparing outputs for two different compilers, a C compiler, and a C++ compiler. Why do you find it odd that the output differs?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl to be fair, because both programs do the same, I wonder about the same. The second JMP is a bit useless, at a first glance.

Comment: Also, as far I remember, there is no exact rules in C nor C++ languages that would say that a `goto` MUST be translated to a specific JMP instruction. The compiler has to produce a binary form that when executed, will produce effects the same as if the code was executed. The "as is" is an important feature. There are LOTS of things that are not translated 1-to-1 directly as in the code. If you need exact assembly output, use embedded assembly snippet, or assembly module that will be added on linking phase.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, I find it odd as well

Comment: [here is repro](https://godbolt.org/z/aYjsfYEj6)

Comment: Who cares if you are not using optimizations? When optimizations are enabled there is no difference and obsolete code was removed: https://godbolt.org/z/oTYPqYM94

Comment: Debug or Release (Optimized)? If debug why do you care?  The objective of a non-optimized build is to make debugging easier.

Comment: I am more surprised the compiler doesn't throw out the assembly for ` printf("skipped\n");` completely. It is unreachable code so can be removed. Did you compile with any optimization on?

Comment: UPinar: finishing my thought - despite what I said, compilers, especially from the same vendor like MS, usually behave in a similar way (unless language-specific things are used ofc). However, to be able to tell something, if anyone attempts to, will probably require you to provide exact information how you build those files: optimisation flags, build modes like debug/release, target platform, etc etc. Then, finally, even compilers have bugs, but it's far from saying you found one.

Comment: Could well be a compiler bug, that isn't caught in any of the (unit) tests.

Answer (score 6):

It is like this by design in debug builds (msvc bug database) see :
[S2019 (debug, x86) generates two identical JMP instructions for one goto statement](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2019-debug-x86-generates-two-identi/919492?q=jmp+instruction+emitted)

Comment: Some comments in the link state it was filed as a bug, another says it is by design. So why doesn't the OP's C compiler also do this? Because it was not a debug compilation?

Comment: Perhaps this answer should be expanded to say how this links to C++ destructor placement, as mentioned in the linked page.

Comment: Seconded TomV's suggestion to include more detail in the actual answer, not just behind the link.  The last comment in the linked thread has source code for a test-case that apparently sheds some light on it; quoting that source and showing how it compiles would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score -1):

C and C++ are two completely different programming languages.

Different compilers are used to compile them. The actual compiler might be a single, monolithic program, but functionally there are two logically distinct compilers and algorithms, that have nothing to do with each other.

It is not entirely unexpected that different compilers will generate different compiled code from syntactically identical source. The differences in the resulting compiled code result from the different algorithms that are employed by the different compilers, when translating the source code. The differences carry no special, inherent meaning.

Comment: What if we rephrased the question to ignore the C-mode output of MSVC for a moment and asked whether MSVC's C++ compiler emits machine code containing the exact same JMP twice in direct succession. (which fits, because that's actually the last sentence marked as "Question is…")

Comment: The answer would vary only slightly: it's a result of this C++ compiler's internal algorithms, it carries no specific meaning, it's dead code, and a different C++ compiler might produce completely different result from the same source; additionally the same C++ compiler produced different result, from the same C++ source, all the time, depending on the compilation options.

Comment: No questioning the "doesn't need to be consistent with others" aspect, but it's not usual for a compiler to emit dead code. In the end that only makes the machine code worse in terms of fetchability/compactness…

Comment: With the "disable all optimization options", most compilers will faithfully reproduce dead code in source code form, that happens all the time. It's not a stretch that a "disable all optimization options" may also cause bits of dead code to peek out in the compiled results, even when not present. Note that the shown source code is highly unusual, rare, and it's entirely plausible that compilers are simply not optimized for kinds of code that's not practically used.

Comment: Cobol and c++ are two completely different programming languages. If the same code can be compiled by a c compiler and a c++ compiler and do the same thing then they are not 'completly different languages ' . I get why you say this but it's simply not true

Comment: There's only one `goto` in the source; not doing dead code removal doesn't explain an unreachable `jmp`, only the dead `lea`/`call`.  (Also, GCC and clang *do* perform dead-code removal even in debug builds https://godbolt.org/z/5ba9rfcrv; MSVC is the exception in my experience in not doing so.  I haven't looked much at any non-mainstream compilers or for other languages.  Of course in a debug build, code is only dead if controlled by `if(false)` or skipped by a goto, not `x=0; if(x)` because there's no constant-propagation for variables not declared `const`.)